# Flutter : line 33: sed: command not found

Tags: flutter

I was going through the installation steps of [Flutter](https://flutter.io/setup-macos/)

I have done all the steps which are given for MAC

but when running `flutter` command, it is showing

```
/Users/mac005/sdk/bin/flutter: line 33: sed: command not found
```

Comment: What do you get when you enter `sed` in a shell window?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer actualy i was setting path in wrong way

Answer (score 5):

There was issue with path setting.

I was doing

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin
```

So it was not able to recognize any other command in terminal.

Actual command was

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: that is the right answer. If you type echo `pwd` you get the actual path. So the command is `export PATH=/User/your_user/path/to/flutter/bin:$PATH`.